# Reinstaling NSS library on CentOS (Amazon AMI)

Tags: centos, rpm, nss

I had a problem during updating of the packages on CentOS AMI from Amazon (S3).

I got a bunch of duplicated packages. Among them:

```
nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2.3-14.2.38.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2.3-1.13.amzn1.x86_64
```

I've removed a duplicate with `rpm -e nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2.3-14.2.38.amzn1.x86_64`

This caused the `yum`, `rpm` and other commands to immediately stop working with errors like this:

```
error: Failed to initialize NSS library There was a problem importing one of the Python modules required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   cannot import name ts

Please install a package which provides this module, or verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the current version of Python, which is:
2.6.9 (unknown, Mar 28 2014, 00:06:37)  [GCC 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to  the yum faq at:   http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

`rpm` → `error: Failed to initialize NSS library`

etc.

Any idea how to fix the server (reinstall `nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2.3-14.2.38.amzn1.x86_64`) without `rpm` command, `rpm2cpio` (also depends on NSS apparently)?

Or make Python use the other installed NSS version?

Answer (score 1):

Today I meet a similar problems like this.

I use rpm -e  --nodeps  sqlit ...rpm
 then the problem occur like below.

```
# rpm 
error: Failed to initialize NSS library
```

This link help me out of the trouble. 
https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/75684/how-to-recover-yumdnfrpm-after-uninstall-sqlite/

The core command is here :

"sqlite-3.8.10.2-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm"   Just as a demo rpm.

```
# rpm2cpio sqlite-3.8.10.2-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv 
Retrieving the sqlite-3.8.10.2-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm  package to cpio format.
#rpm -ivh sqlite 
Install sqlite
```

Then your rpm / yum / dnf will be back .